# Error handling for React Tableau JS API integration

Tags: reactjs, tableau-api

I am integrating tableau js API in react app for loading the dashboard of my application.
The positive flow is successfully integrated and need to handle the negative use case. For tableau-viz webcomponent, I can see, it loads the source in iframe as a shadowRoot content.
But with all this I am not able to track the negative use cases like the
1 - 401(Access denied) in case the wrong or expired token passed to tableau-viz component
2 - 403(Forbidden) error.
3 - 404 in case of incorrect source url for tableau dashboard.
I need to handle all the negative use cases in case where, I need to hide the iframe and display custom error component in react app.

Can someone help me over here, how to handle the negative use cases for tableau page getting load in iframe via tableau-viz webcomponent provided by tableau JS Api, similar to onEventListenerFirstInteractive which gets triggered in success case. Or any approach to handle onerror condition for tableau-viz code.

```html
<tableau-viz
    id='tableauViz'
    ref={vizRef
    toolbar: 'hidden'
    token: "OptionalJWTToken"
    onEventListenerFirstInteractive={(e: any) =>
        console.log(
        "callback example: onEventListenerFirstInteractive:",
        { e }, vizRef.current
    )
    }
    {...props}>  // addon optional Props for tableau-viz
</tableau-viz>
```

[This is how the iframe is loaded via tableau-viz in case of error scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBEDA.png)